# Upload multipart via rested client

Tags: angular, testing, firefox, endpoint

How can I upload a file via multipart post-request with the firefox rested client. I have the problem how to tell the rested client where the file which I wanted to upload is stored on the disc. Or is there a way to save the test-file in the rested client before ? (test.pdf)
I use the following parameters which seems correct:

```
{
  "log": {
    "version": "1.2",
    "creator": "RESTED REST Client",
    "Comment": "An exported collection from RESTED",
    "entries": [
      {
        "request": {
          "method": "POST",
          "url": "https://myurl.de/webservice/upload",
          "headers": [
            {
              "name": "X-Auth-Token",
              "value": "mytoken"
            },
            {
              "name": "Accept-Encoding",
              "value": "multipart/form-data"
            }
          ],
          "postData": {
            "mimeType": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            "params": [
              {
                "name": "uploadedFile",
                "value": "test.pdf"
              },
              {
                "name": "bemerkung",
                "value": "Test2"
              },
              {
                "name": "date",
                "value": "2019-09-06"
              },
              {
                "name": "number",
                "value": "WSM00000008100058"
              },
              {
                "name": "filename",
                "value": "test.pdf"
              }
            ],
            "text": "uploadedFile=test.pdf&bemerkung=Test2&date=2019-09-06&number=WSM00000008100058&filename=test.pdf"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I need a example how to configure the rested client for uploads to use a local file.